# Problem with using two different sum()'s on same column

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to get two different counts on the same column. The first count works fine with the constraints given, but the second count is not counting  correctly. I have two tables, which are `DailyFieldRecord` and `AB953`. `DailyFieldRecord` contains: `DailyFieldRecordID` and `ActivityCodeID`. The `AB953` table contains:`DailyFieldRecordID, ItemID, and GroupID`. `Count1` will return the count of the `DailyfieldrecordID's` that contain `ActivityCodeID=387` and `GroupID=260` and that DON'T have `ItemID in (1302,1303,1305,1306)`. `Count2` will return the count of the `DailyfieldrecordID's` that contain `ActivityCodeID=387` and `GroupID=260` and that HAVE `ItemID in (1302,1303,1305,1306)`. I'm trying to only get the count of the `GroupID =260` for each `DailyFieldRecordID` that corresponds with the above constraints.

```
    DailyFieldRecord:                   AB953:
DailyFieldRecordID ActivityCodeID    DailyFieldRecordID:  ItemID: GroupID:
   657                 387                657               1305    210
   888                 420                657               1333    260
   672                 387                657               1335    260
                                          657               1302    210
                                          657               1334    260
                                          657               1111    111                                              
                                          888               1302    210
                                          888               1336    260
                                          672               1327    260
                                          672               1334    260 
                                          672               1335    260
                                          672               1322    260
                                          672               1222    420

Expected Output:
Count1:      Count2:
   4            3
Count1 is supposed to count:                Count2 is supposed to count:
   672    1327    260                  657     1333     260
   672    1334    260                  657     1335     260
   672    1335    260                  657     1334     260
   672    1322    260

Current Count:
 Count1:       Count2:
   4              6


SELECT sum(CASE WHEN ex=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT1,sum(EX) AS COUNT2
FROM AB953 ab
JOIN DailyFieldRecord dfr
       ON dfr.DailyFieldRecordID = ab.DailyFieldRecordID
JOIN ( SELECT AB1.DailyFieldRecordID,sum(CASE WHEN AB1.ItemID IN 
     (1302,1303,1305,1306) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EX
        FROM AB953 AB1
        GROUP BY AB1.DailyFieldRecordID) T
        ON dfr.DailyFieldRecordID = T.DailyFieldRecordID
WHERE dfr.ActivityCodeID = 387
AND ab.GroupID = 260
```

Answer (score 0):

First need to identify all of the `DailyFieldRecordID`s that have any of the `ItemID`s specified, which is what the sub-query here is doing. Then you can determine if the record in the outer query belongs to `Count1` or `Count2` based on where or not it exists in the result set of the subquery.

```
select sum(case when i.DailyFieldRecordID is null then 1 else 0 end) as Count1
, sum(case when i.DailyFieldRecordID is null then 0 else 1 end) as Count2
from AB953 as ab
inner join DailyFieldRecord as dfr on ab.DailyFieldRecordID = dfr.DailyFieldRecordID
left join (
            select distinct a.DailyFieldRecordID
            from AB953 as a
            where a.ItemID in (1302, 1303, 1305, 1306)
            ) as i on ab.DailyFieldRecordID = i.DailyFieldRecordID
where dfr.ActivityCodeID = 387
and ab.GroupID = 260
```

**Final Output:**

```
+--------+--------+
| Count1 | Count2 |
+--------+--------+
| 4      | 3      |
+--------+--------+
```

Comment: For the first count I'm trying to find the `DailyFieldRecordID`'s that have `ActivityCodeID=387` and `GroupID=260`  that dont contain `ItemID in (1302,1303,1305,1306)` corresponding to the `DailyFieldRecordID`. The second count is the opposite where im trying to find the the `DailyFieldRecordID`'s that have `ActivityCodeID=387` and `GroupID=260`  that do contain `ItemID in (1302,1303,1305,1306)` corresponding to the `DailyFieldRecordID. For the second count, if it does contain `ItemID in (1302,1303,1305,1306)` then I only want to count how many GroupID's = 260 correspond to it

Comment: Right now the second count is counting the number of `ItemID in (1302,1303,1305,1306)` for the corresponding `DailyFieldRecordID`,which is 2 for `1305,1302 in DailyFieldRecord=657`. Its then adding them together for each row where `Groupid=260` , which there are 3 of them. I only want it to count all of the `ItemID in (1302,1303,1305,1306)` as 1 regardless how how many there are for each DailyFieldRecordID.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(dfr.ActivityCodeID)
FROM AB953 ab
JOIN DailyFieldRecord dfr ON dfr.DailyFieldRecordID = ab.DailyFieldRecordID
WHERE GroupID=260 AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT b.DailyFieldRecordID
 FROM AB953 b
 WHERE ab.DailyFieldRecordID=b.DailyFieldRecordID AND b.ItemID IN ( 1302,1303,1305,1306 ) )
 AND dfr.ActivityCodeID=387` This query works for the second count, but I dont know how to encorporate it to make both counts work.

Comment: I believe I understand what you're trying to do now. Take a look at my modified answer.

Comment: Great! FYI - Its customary to accept an answer when it solves your issue.